# Minimum operations to convert number to 1

Tags: java, algorithm

Given a number N and number K, find minimum number of operations to convert N to 1.
allowed operations:

- subtract 1
- divide by 2 (at most K times)

here is my code but it is not working correctly.

```
  private int getMinRounds(int N, int K, int memo[]) 
  { 
      if(N <= 1) return 0;
      if (memo[N] != -1) return memo[N];
      
      int rounds;
      if ((N%2) == 0 && K > 0) {
          rounds = 1 + Math.min(getMinRounds(N-1, K, memo), getMinRounds(N/2, K-1, memo));
      }else {
          rounds = 1 + getMinRounds(N-1, K, memo);
      }
      memo[N] = rounds; 
      return rounds; 
  }

  private int solution(int N, int K) 
  { 
      int memo[] = new int[N + 1];
      Arrays.fill(memo, -1);
      return getMinRounds(N, K, memo); 
  }
```

Comment: "*it is not working correctly*" **What** about it is not working correctly? Please be specific - don't leave potential answerers guessing.

Comment: for example if N = 18 and K = 2. expected answer is 6 but it returns 5

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5221149) Or did you simply expect us to debug your code for you for free?

Comment: *Hint:* Try changing `memo` to a 2D array `int[N + 1][K + 1]`. The method has 2 independent arguments, so the result of calling with a particular `N` is not always the same, since the result also depends on `K`.

Comment: @Andreas thank you so much for the hint, I guess that exactly what I was missing. And sorry if my question wasn't clear or lacked information.

Comment: @rock It's not that the question is unclear or lacks information, it's that it lacks *work* on your part, i.e. the *attempt* at identifying the problem by **debugging** the code. See e.g. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A greedy aproach should be enough to solve this problem. The bigger the number is, the best it is to divide it by 2 already, so you don't need to think "*is it better to divide now or store the division for later?*". The bigger the number you can divide is, the best for you it will be to divide it.

```
int solve (int n, int k){
    if(n == 1) return 0;
    if(k == 0) return n - 1;
    if(n % 2 == 0) return 1 + solve(n / 2, k - 1);
    return 1 + solve(n - 1, k);
}
```

Complexity: O(log(n))

---

**OUTPUTS** *solve(n, k)*

```
solve(1, 1) = 0
solve(2, 2) = 1
solve(3, 3) = 2
solve(4, 0) = 3
solve(5, 1) = 3
solve(6, 2) = 3
solve(7, 3) = 4
solve(8, 0) = 7
solve(9, 1) = 5
solve(10, 2) = 4
```